# How to fetch the Data from MySQL Db which is greater than Or equal to Today's date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch the Data from MySQL Db which is greater than Or equal to Today's date, In my Db, the date format is in d/m/Y. And I have nearly 50 records which are greater than today's date but it is retrieving only a few records.

```
<?php
$currentdate = date('Y-m-d');
$date = str_replace('-', '/', $currentdate);
$tdate= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
// $tdate = date("Y/m/d");
echo $query1 = "SELECT * FROM strategic_batch where batch_sdate ='$tdate'";
?>
```

Please help me if there is another way. I found the other way but the data is not fetching.

```
<?php 
echo SELECT * FROM strategic_batch WHERE batch_sdate >= CURDATE(); 
?>
```

[My database records.  Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMbvS.png)

[when I try to fetch the data I get only this records. Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCtpO.png)

Answer (score 0):

change 'batch_sdate =' to 'batch_sdate >='

The equal sign will check for exact match. Since you want all records greater than or equals to a particular date, you have to use the >= sign.

This will only work if batch_sdate type is date or datetime as mysql would know how to interpret it. If it is a string, it will not work.

Comment: I tried with your changes but i getting only a few records. I need all records which are greater than or equal to today's date

Comment: What type is batch_sdate? Is it date or string?

Comment: it is a string type

Comment: Ah. Ok in order to do ranges, you have to change the type to date

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Noted. Added explanation